# Replacing empty fields by zero in a csv file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a csv file with 9 columns where every three of them has different rows. The file looks like

```
1  6.2   0.5  1  0.08  0.5   1  0.001  0.1
2  5.2   0.6  2  0.01  1.3   2  0.008  0.8
3  4.3   0.7  3  0.002 0.32
4  2.0   0.7  4  0.2   0.35
5  13.1  1.3  5  0.54  4.32
6  1.02  1.67
```

I would like to replace any empty field by zero using a bash script. 
The outcome that I would like to produce should look like

```
1  6.2   0.5  1  0.08  0.5   1  0.001  0.1
2  5.2   0.6  2  0.01  1.3   2  0.008  0.8
3  4.3   0.7  3  0.002 0.32  3  0      0
4  2.0   0.7  4  0.2   0.35  4  0      0
5  13.1  1.3  5  0.54  4.32  5  0      0
6  1.02  1.67 6  0     0     6  0      0
```

Comment: Is the file tab-delimited? What should the output look like?

Comment: yes, it is tab-delimited. In principle, I need to have the 4th, 7th, 10th, .. have the numbers as my first column. and the rest should be zero.

Comment: Are the missing columns always the last ones? I don't see 21 columns here, only 9. Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output.

Comment: Every three columns have the same number of filled rows, e.g. 1-3, 4-6, 7-9. The missing files are the same in each of these columns. For instance, in the provided test file, one row in the 4-6 line is missing and 4 rows in the 7-9 columns are also empty.

Comment: [phk’s answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/337551/80216#337573) produces the output that you ask for given the input you provide.  If that’s not what you want, (1) provide an example dataset (input and output) that *does* Illustrate what you want, and (2) explain it in clear English.   (“the number of rows is also considered as a column” is not clear, and I guess “the number of raw” is a typo for “the number of rows”.)  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution hard-coded for the number of columns and assuming only the latter columns are the ones possibly empty:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" } {
  $1=NR; if(!$2)$2=0; if(!$3)$3=0;
  $4=NR; if(!$5)$5=0; if(!$6)$6=0;
  $7=NR; if(!$8)$8=0; if(!$9)$9=0;
  print }' /path/to/your.csv
```

Comment: Thank you. But this didn't work. the problems are the number of rows is also considered as a column and setting empty lines with zero would only apply if the number of raw is less than that. I was trying to fix the second problem by using the longest column, but the first problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -v cols=9 '{
    printf "%s", $0
    for (n = NF; n < cols; n++) printf "\t%d", (n % 3 == 0 ? NR : 0)
    print ""
}' file
```

The number of columns is passed as variable `cols` so you can change it easily. I didn't bother aligning output data.